# Ubuntu 16.04 can't connect to WiFi unless Secure Boot is disabled

Tags: 16.04, wireless, secure-boot

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 recently, but I can't connect to WiFi unless Secure Boot is disabled. Is there any better solution or do I have to keep Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: If it works with secure boot off it's because the WiFi drivers aren't signed. Either keep it disabled or sign the drivers (Mokutil?? Not sure, never did it)

Comment: @karel See the last paragraph of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/350567).

Comment: @iBug That answer was recently edited (yesterday!) and it was accurate when it was originally posted, but sadly it's no longer a definitive answer to that Meta Stack Exchange question. Someone should put a +100 bonus on that question so that it could get a more up-to-date answer.

Comment: @karel Despite the fact that the answer was edited recently, [Stack Overflow stated](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/) something similar in their blog 9 years ago.

Comment: That is a very good blog post and it is still up-to-date even after 9 years, however I don't see anywhere in that blog post that it is forbidden to translate a non-English question into English. We have many bilingual users at Ask Ubuntu who are able to provide perfect translations of their native languages into English and save quality posts from the reviewer hammer. Note that I'm not saying that all non-English posts are high quality, and if a non-English post is low quality sometimes I will avoid editing it.

Comment: @iBug In Ask Ubuntu community it's pretty acceptable to translate other language posts according to their merit (refer to [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1506/what-to-do-with-non-english-questions-or-answers), [this](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6853/does-it-make-sense-to-flag-non-english-questions)). If I'm not mistaken, flagging/voting as unclear is also equally acceptable.